# django development server restarts itself while performing long script

Tags: python, sql-server, django

I'm using Django 1.8.1 with MSSQL Server connection. I'm testing this one big function in which I iterate through 250 records and insert each into the SQL server.

My problem is that at the middle of the script, the Django server just restarts itself every single time. In the log, there's no error message. it's just a message that I always get when I do "python manage.py runserver". See pasted below.

For further info, my function logic is basically:

1. Trigger data pull
2. Get data from an external data warehouse (about 250 records) into a DataFrame
3. For each row in the DataFrame, perform a simple logic and then insert data into Table 1 at SQL Server
4. After step 3, open table 1 at SQL server and perform another logic and update the record on table 1.
5. Return to home page with success / failure message.

Can anyone help me troubleshoot this? I don't even see any error message to know where to start. Also if you have any recommendation on how to improve the workflow above (aka may be better way to process large number of record?) please let me know.

Thank you all.

```
[08/Apr/2018 23:34:47]"GET /TK/6/?RunDate=2018-04-08 HTTP/1.1" 500 198625
Performing system checks...
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
April 08, 2018 - 23:35:05
Django version 1.8.1, using settings 'MyApp.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
[08/Apr/2018 23:35:14]"GET /admin/Timekeeping/timereviewstaff/ HTTP/1.1" 200 3008
[08/Apr/2018 23:35:14]"GET /admin/jsi18n/ HTTP/1.1" 200 2344
```

Comment: Is there any reason why loading the data has to happen in a request/response cycle? Is it a one-time data load, or something that will happen regularly?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question... This is a procedure I'll have to do every week - each data pull is one week of data.

Comment: I was wondering whether this operation may be best implemented as a Django management command, rather than within a web request. It could be that the data load takes long enough that the request times out, triggering the auto restart that you’re seeing. Using a management command for the data load would mean you wouldn’t hit this kind of issue